# Is there a function that never vanishes, and can never reach infinity?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

Is there a (non-constant) function $f(z)$ in the Riemann sphere such that for all z, 
$f(z) \neq 0, \infty$ ?

In other words, is there a function that never vanishes, and can never reach infinity?

I am convinced there is no such function, however why is this true? Is there a magical Theorem somewhere proving this?

Comment: The question in the title and the question in the body of your post are practically unrelated. Which do you mean to ask?

Comment: Also, I suspect you are also omitting crucial details; e.g. wanting a function to be complex-valued and complex analytic.

Comment: Apologies, the title is now more appropriate. Would I have to assume $f$ is complex analytic for the statement to be correct?

Comment: When you say "can never reach infinity" would you consider a function like $f(z)=|z|+1$ to work?  Certainly, regardless the value of $z$, so long as it is finite (*which all elements of $\Bbb C$ are*) the output is a finite positive real number.  Do not confuse limits and end behavior with actually attaining those values.  If that doesn't work for you, then how about something which oscillates such as $f(z)=\sin(|z|)+2$ which is always a real number between $1$ and $3$.

Comment: The tags of this question also need to be edited.

Answer (score 2):

What about $f(z)=\frac{|z|^2+1}{|z|^2+2}$?

If you want the function to be analytic, then [Liouville's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)) says that any bounded entire function must be constant.

Answer (score 0):

Why not $f(z) \equiv 1, \quad \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: I edited the question so that $f(z)$ is non-constant

Comment: Ok, then, $f(z)=1$ when $z\neq z_0,$ but $f(z_0)=2,$ where $z_0$ is some predetermined point in the domain. We can come up with silly examples like this all day until you make the question say what you really want to ask. My guess is someone stated something very important about $f$ that you forgot to tell us. (Or you can get lucky and someone posts a function that actually satisfies your unstated requirements.)